# Postgres вернуть ид из WITH

Tags: postgresql

такой запрос

```
    WITH insert_foo AS
     (INSERT INTO analiz_create (name, template_id)
      VALUES (
                (SELECT nam.name
                 FROM vgok_site.a_template_name nam,
                      vgok_site.a_template TEMP
                 WHERE TEMP.name_id = nam.id
                   AND TEMP.id = $zn_template), $zn_template) returning id)
    INSERT INTO analiz_data ( elem_id, analiz_id, value)
    VALUES (84,
             (SELECT id
              FROM insert_foo),
              $id_lvl)
    RETURNING id
```

т.е. сначала я создаю запись в таблице - шапке, а затем используя полученный ид записываю в таблицу-дочку значение, используя полученный ид.

если сделать в конце ретурн, то получу ид из таблицы-дочки, а мне хочется получить ид из шапки

Answer (score 1):

в этом случае нужно написать не

> RETURNING id

а

> RETURNING analiz_id